# ArrayList is not being initiating on every user click (onClick) Android

Tags: android, variables, arraylist

I think it's weird but I can't initiate my `ArrayList` in `onClick` method.
here is the code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SelectedCoinsListener selectedCoinsListener = this;
    List<SelectCurrency> finalList;
    finalList = this.currenciesPair;

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.fromCurrency :
            if (toCurrency != null) {

                for (int i = 0 ; i < finalList.size() ; i++ ){

                    if (finalList.get(i).getCurrencyId() == toCurrency) {
                        finalList.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            customAlertDialogList = new CustomAlertDialogList(getContext(), finalList, selectedCoinsListener, false);
            break;
}
```

I want to get a copy of the original list every time the user clicks, send the list to a function, and repeat the same operation by clicking again, but by executing the above code, the same copy is reused and the original list is not being copied every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects don't work that way in Java. When you do this:

```
finalList = this.currenciesPair;
```

you're basically creating two pointers to the same Object. So if you do `finalList.remove(i)`, whatever element was at `i` will also be removed from `currenciesPair`.

If you want to make a copy, the ArrayList class has a handy constructor:

```
List<SelectCurrency> finalList = new ArrayList(currenciesPair);
```

This doesn't make an `ArrayList<ArrayList<SelectCurrency>>` like it might seem. If you actually look at the code for that constructor, you'll see it loops through the given Collection (List, Set, ArrayList, ArraySet, etc) and adds the values to the ArrayList being created. So instead of making two pointers for the same Object, you have two separate Objects that have the same contents.

EDIT:

I recommend using an iterator instead of a standard for loop. It's just a little bit cleaner:

```
for (SelectCurrency currency : currenciesPair) {
    if (currency.getCurrencyId() == toCurrency) finalList.remove(currency)
}
```

Notice how I'm using `currenciesPair` and not `finalList` in the for line.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a simpler way to send all the list data except some of them without having to copy the list?

Comment: You can use `stream()` to filter and then collect to a new Collection instance inline, but I wouldn't call it simpler. I am going to edit a suggestion for logic into my answer though.